# error insert into oracle

Tags: oracle, insert

```
insert into BDD_CDC.T_CONFIGURATION ( varString1, codOffice, varString2) 
select 'OFFICE', ofi.codOffice, 'SELECT'  
from BDD_CDC.T_OFFICE ofi;
```

I don't know why this is not working. I got this error:

```
Error SQL: ORA-00904: "VARSTRING2": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: It means you dont have a column called varString2 in the table BDD_CDC.T_CONFIGURATION

Comment: Can you share the structure of the `T_CONFIGURATION` table?

Comment: You are right SHANKAR.  I was convinced I had to write the same number of variables that the table T_CONFIGURATION has as columns, not their name. Really thanks

Comment: Ok cool, added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you dont have a column called varString2 in the table BDD_CDC.T_CONFIGURATION